# Why is fetched data not being displayed on the web page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, jsx

I am getting data and from API and have a conditional rendering with Loader. Sometimes all the data is displayed on the page but often the Loader displays but never the data. I cannot understand the reason why this is so.

It looks like the problem usually occurs on the smartphone and not on the computer.

```
useEffect(() => {
navigator.geolocation &&
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=${metric_units}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('Network Error');
        console.error('API call error:', error);
      });
  });
```

}, []);

```
  let localDay = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCDay();
  let localDate = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCDate();
  let localMonth = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCMonth();
  let localHours = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCHours();
  let localMinutes = new Date((data.dt + data.timezone) * 1000).getUTCMinutes();





{Object.keys(data).length === 0 ? (
        <PuffLoader color={'#ffffff'} size={200} className='loader' />
      ) : (
        <div className='content'>
          {/* ********** TOP-SECTION ********** */}

          <section className='top-section'>
            <div className='location'>
              <p>{data.name}</p>
              {data.sys && <p>, {data.sys.country}</p>}
            </div>

            <div className='date-time'>
              {
                <p className='date'>
                  {weekdays[localDay]}, {months[localMonth]} {localDate}
                </p>
              }
              {
                <p className='time'>
                  {localHours < 10 ? '0' + localHours : '' + localHours}:
                  {localMinutes < 10 ? '0' + localMinutes : '' + localMinutes}
                </p>
              }
            </div>

            <div className='temp-icon'>
              <div className='temp'>
                {data.main && <h1>{data.main.temp.toFixed()} °C</h1>}
              </div>
              <div className='icon-div'>
                {data.weather && (
                  <img
                    className='icon'
                    src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
                    alt='weather icon'
                  ></img>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className='description'>
                {data.weather && <p>{data.weather[0].description}</p>}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='description-feels-like'>
              <div className='feels-like'>
                {data.main && (
                  <p>Feels like {data.main.feels_like.toFixed()} °C</p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

          {/* ********** BOTTOM-SECTION ********** */}

          {data.name !== undefined && (
            <section className='bottom-section'>
              <div className='humidity'>
                {data.main && <p className='bold'>{data.main.humidity} %</p>}
                <p>Humidity</p>
              </div>

              <div className='pressure'>
                {data.main && <p className='bold'>{data.main.pressure} mb</p>}
                <p>Pressure</p>
              </div>

              <div className='wind'>
                {data.wind && (
                  <p className='bold'>{data.wind.speed.toFixed()} m/s</p>
                )}
                <p>Wind</p>
              </div>
            </section>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you didn't pass any dependency to the useEffect, and it works only one time in page load, so you need to pass the `setData` to the useEffect as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation &&
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        axios
          .get(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=${metric_units}`
          )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setData(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert('Network Error');
            console.error('API call error:', error);
          });
      });
  }, [setData]);
```

Comment: It does not work. You can't specify setData as a dependency, but it should be data.

Comment: When you set an empty dependency to useEffect, it works only on the page's first load, and because you use the async Axios it will not update your data state variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are working on VITE, Have you made the changes to the Vite.config.js?
Here is how you do. I assume you are using port 8080 in your Backend

```
server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
```